# Text file reading and handling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, filereader

I'm trying to write a function in which a text file can be selected, read, and used as a variable which can then be split into an array of individual words. When it tries to run the readAsText method, I get the error that this.files[0] is undefined.

```
 <pre id="contents"></pre>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function findWord() { 
            function readFile() {
                var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = function() {
                    document.getElementById('contents').textContent = this.result;
                };
                fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
            }
            var myText = document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', readFile());
            var words = myText.split(" ");
            var foundWord = words[0];
            document.write(foundWord);
        }
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
<input type="submit" value="Find Word" onclick="findWord();" />
```

Comment: Of course you do. You've assigned `myText` the result of calling the function `addEventListener`. That function doesn't return anything. So `myText` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

[`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) expects a function as second argument.

You pass `readFile()` as the second argument. `readFile()` is not a function. It's the result of calling the function `readFile`. When you call that function (to pass its result to `EventTarget.addEventListener`), `this.files[0]` is undefined, because `this` still references the global object, which does not have a `files` property.

Pass `readFile` as second argument to `EventTarget.addEventListener`, instead of `readFile()`.

Comment: That's certainly part of the problem.

Comment: ...but hardly the only part. The code would need a complete rewrite to actually work.